# How to render some word insted of 'true' or 'false' values fetched from api into the FlatList?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am able to get arrays of 'true' or 'false' values of many data from the api.
How can i render 'Hello' if value is 'true' and 'Good Night' otherwise for all the data fetched. I used String(item.attributes.status) to show true or false value. I have an api having many data with attributes such as boolean valued 'status'.

```
<FlatList

  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}

  data={this.state.companies}
  renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => (

    <View>
      <Text style={styles.listText}>{item.attributes.status}</Text>

    </View>

 )}

 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

/>

getCompanies = () => {
  console.log('getCompanies function');

  this.setState({ loading: true }, () =>
  {
    fetch('https://------------------------------------',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers:
      {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': '------------------------------------------------',
      },

    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response');
      return response.json()
      this.setState({ loading: false});

    })
    .then(RetrivedData => {
      // Work with JSON data here
      console.log('Retrived Data');

      if(RetrivedData.success){

        console.log('Success');
        this.setState({
          companies: RetrivedData.data
        });

      }
      else{
        Alert.alert('Error !!!!!!!!');
      }
      this.setState({ loading: false});

      })
      .catch(err => {
      // Do something for an error here
      this.setState({ loading: false});
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take shorthand of if. This:

```
true ? 'True' : 'False'
```

will return 'True' just like this:

```
if (true) {return 'True'}; else {return 'False'};
```

Try writing your Text in this way:

```
<Text style={styles.listText}>{item.attributes.status ? 'Hello' : 'Good Night'}</Text>
```